# How do you configure Qt 6 so that the ABI is `asmjs-unknown-unknown-emscripten-32bit` and not `x86-linux-generic-elf-64bit`?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, webassembly, emscripten

I have been trying to compile a version of Qt Web Assembly on 6.2.

The compile seems to go fine, however, when I import it into QtCreator, it says that the ABI is x86, which I presume it is the reason which I can not use it for compiling web assembly
[image]

It should instead say

```
ABI:
asmjs-unknown-unknown-emscripten-32bit
```

As that is what my working web assembly build has. This is my configure line, and I got it from reading the tutorial:

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/wasm.html

```
./configure -feature-thread -device-option QT_WASM_SOURCE_MAP=1 -debug -qt-host-path /home/anon/Library/qt6.2/qtbase -xplatform wasm-emscripten -prefix $PWD/qtbase
```

What is going on here? Do I perhaps have to explicitly set this line here:

> Although it should be detected, you may optionally set the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PATH to the Emscripten.cmake toolchain file that comes with Emscripten sdk, by using the -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE= configure argument.

If above is the case, how do I do that? I am not quite sure what file I would be editting in that case.